# Jquery ajax results not displaying properly in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a site I'm working on which uses ajax to load page segments when js is available - this used to work in all browsers, the only problem being that the browser history was only updated in HTML5 broswers.

I have recently been doing a lot of work on the site and most recently decided to try to sort the history out for html4 browsers, in doing so I have checked the site in IE and found that a problem has developed with the way the data from some of the ajax calls is being displayed (only affecting IE - not FF).

The URLS are structured as follows:

> sitename.dev/main_category/sub_category

if I just enter `sitename.dev/main_category` everything works fine but if I click the link for one of the sub categories at `sitename.dev/main_category/sub_category` the results are loaded but not displayed properly in IE. If I type the address into the browser for hard reload all works fine

**WORKING (through hard reload):**
[image: WORKING (through hard reload):]

**Not working through ajax:**

[image: Not working through ajax:]

Because it is ajax loaded content I cannot inspect the dom, but my function appears to be firing correctly and the ajax call is returning the correct results.

Here is the code for my ajax call

```
function leftsort_click(event) { //main sort click (left menu)
    var page = window.name, page_index,
    api = $('#right_pane').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    maintainPosition: false
    }).data('jsp');

    if (!$(this).hasClass('sort_cat')) {

    $('ul.sort_ul li, ul.cat_items li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var sid = $(this).attr('id');
    var title = $(this).html();
    var loadUrlx= page;
    if ((sid != '') && (sid != 'undefined')) {
        loadUrlx += '/'+sid;
    }
    if($('.rpp_btn.active').length>=1){
        var res_per_page = $.trim($('.rpp_btn.active').html());
        page_index = $.trim($('.res_page_select.active a').html());
        if (($('.rpp_btn.active').hasClass('just_clicked'))||(!$('.res_page_select').hasClass('just_clicked'))) {
        page_index = '1';
        }
        if ((page_index != 1) || (res_per_page != 25)) {
        loadUrlx += '/' + page_index + '/' + res_per_page;
        }
        $('.rpp_btn, .res_page_select').removeClass('just_clicked');
    }

    loadUrlx = b_url + loadUrlx;
    if (History.enabled) {
        History.pushState(null, null, loadUrlx);

    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    $("#result_area").load(loadUrlx, function() {
        $("#result_table").trigger("update");
        api.reinitialise();
        tsizer();
    });
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked this one out, i was injecting a div into a tbody - Ie's not happy about that.